# how to set font-family to div which have many children and sub -children?

Tags: html, css, fonts

How to set font family to entire div? The DIV have a lot of children and those children have a lot of sub-children. I want font-family to be applied to all of them. But it does not work for some reasons.

Here is the sample.

```
<div class="page ng-scope" onmousedown="return false;" onselectstart="return false;" ng-include="" src="fileName">              <li class="x-berschrift-2 ng-scope"><span class="char-style-override-9">2.3 </span>Gestaltung der Arbeitsorganisation und der Arbeitsbedingungen</li>

            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope">Die zunehmende Zerlegung der Arbeitsaufgaben im Zuge der Rationalisierung industrieller Produktionsprozesse (Taylorismus) rief in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts Kritik an der „seelenlosen“ monotonen Fabrikarbeit hervor. Ab Mitte der 1960er Jahre drängte eine massive Gegenbewegungen auf Humanisierung und Demokratisierung in der Arbeitswelt. </p>
            <ol class="ng-scope">
                <li class="x-berschrift-3"><span class="char-style-override-10">2.3.1   </span>Klassische und neue Formen der Arbeitsorganisation</li>
            </ol>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope">Der Begriff „Arbeitsorganisation“ wurde im Rahmen der Kritik am Taylorismus geprägt und wurde als Programm zur Überwindung stark arbeitsteiliger und hoch hierarchischer Arbeitsstrukturen aufgefasst. Die Arbeitsstrukturierung war von Anfang an auf eine Verringerung von Arbeitsteilung in Organisationen gerichtet.</p>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope"></p>
            <div class="Definition-Box frame-11 ng-scope">
                <p class="Definition-Titel">DEFINITION ARbeitsorganisation</p>
                <p class="Definition-Flie-text">Unter Arbeitsorganisation/-strukturierung versteht man die organisatorische Gestaltung aller Elemente des Arbeitens nach Art, Umfang und Bedingungen. Sie umfasst alle Maßnahmen zur Veränderung der Arbeitsorganisation und ist damit Teil der Arbeitsgestaltung. </p>
            </div>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope"></p>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope"></p>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope"></p>
            <div class="Fragebox frame-14 ng-scope">
                <div class="Fragezeichenbox frame-13">
                    <p class="Fragezeichen-f-r-Box">?</p>
                </div>
                <p class="Fragebox">Welche klassischen und neuen Formen der Arbeitsorganisation werden unterschieden?</p>
            </div>
            <p class="Flie-text-normal ng-scope"><br></p>
            <table id="table-22" class="Tabelle-nur-Titel-links ng-scope">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="Row-Column-76">
                    <col class="Row-Column-77">
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="Row-Column-100">
                        <td class="Zellen-Titel-nur-links">
                            <p class="Tabelle-Titel-links">Traditionelle(klassische) Formen der Arbeitsorganisation</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Jobenlargement, Jobenrichment, Jobrotation</li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Problemlösegruppen </li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Werkstattgruppen</li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Lernstattgruppen</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Row-Column-101">
                        <td class="Zellen-Titel-nur-links">
                            <p class="Tabelle-Titel-links">Neuere Formen <br>der Arbeitsorganisation</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="Zellen-Body-Rows-normal">
                            <p class="Flie-text-klein">Immer schneller wachsende Märkte machten eine dynamische Form der Arbeitsorganisation notwendig, wie</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Lean Production und Lean Management </li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Teilautonome Arbeitsgruppen (TAG) </li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Teamarbeit</li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Qualitätszirkel </li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Projektgruppen</li>
                                <li class="Aufz-hlung-in-Tabelle"><span class="Aufz-hlungszeichen-Tabelle char-style-override-12">• </span>Gruppensitzungen </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

I have tried to set font-family to this like;

```
.page{
font-family: *font-name*;
}
```

But it does not apply the font-family to the content. Can anyone here help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specifically target all child elements:

```
.page * {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```